# {Wordpress } Use Select Box instead of Default Dropdown for products with variables?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, woocommerce

after searching for a while it seems i cant find an answer,
Picture For reference:

[image: Picture for reference]

I use the "WooCommerce Variation Swatches and Photos" plugins to display color swatches for some products , but for others which have multiple variations i would like to display select boxes , because it's just text.
couldn't figure this , thanks for any help!